# Displaying attribute name in .html file by QGIS2Web

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, attribute-table, html, qgis2web

In QGIS file I have many attributes in my shapefile:

[image]

Then I export file to .html by QGIS2Web plugin:

[image]

But when I click in .html file on my object(shapefile), there are no names of attributes, just their values.

[image]

I want to display also names of attributes.
How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

Change the inline label to header label

Answer (score 0):

I suspect this is because of qgis2web's lack of any good support for layer groups. Test by taking the layer in question out of any layer groups, and see if that fixes the problem (while making sure that you retain the header or inline label settings.

If that is the cause, I am afraid there is no solution to this issue. See: https://github.com/tomchadwin/qgis2web/issues/175